# Map 3D array to cells in Google Sheet - Apps Scirpt

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hey I am trying to place arrays of data into a Google Sheet. I've got a list of dimensions which I am mapping through a function calling an external API to get numerical values for each dimension. I then want to input these into my spreadsheet - however I am unsure how to do this. I would also like to input the specific Date into a column as well. So ideal output would be column A = date, column B = dimensions, column C = numerical value.

```
function function() {
  var dimensions = ["CN","IN","NZ","US","UK","MY","SG","JP","KR","DE"];
  var counts = dimensions.map(dim => [getValue(dim)]);
}

function getValue(dim) {
  // ive removed the detail for the API call
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchUrl, params);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataSet = json.results;

  Logger.log(dataSet);

  return dataSet;

}
```

[image: Logger results]

Answer (score 2):

In your script, for example, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function function() {
  var dimensions = ["CN","IN","NZ","US","UK","MY","SG","JP","KR","DE"];
  var counts = dimensions.map(dim => [getValue(dim)]);
}
```

#### To:

```
function sample() {
  var dimensions = ["CN","IN","NZ","US","UK","MY","SG","JP","KR","DE"];
  var date = new Date();
  var counts = dimensions.map(dim => [date, dim, getValue(dim)[0].aggregations[0].value]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, counts.length, counts[0].length).setValues(counts);
}
```

- `function` cannot be used as the function name.
- From your showing log, I thought that your expected value from the URL might be `dataSet[0].dimensions[0].value]`.
- From `ive removed the detail for the API call`, I cannot see your whole script. In your script, `fetch` is used in a loop. For example, when you use `fetchAll` method, the process cost might be able to be reduced. But, in this case, it is required to also modify `getValue` function.
- If you want to use this script as the custom function, how about the following script? By this, you can retrieve the result values by putting `=sample()` to a cell.

  ```
    function sample() {
      var dimensions = ["CN","IN","NZ","US","UK","MY","SG","JP","KR","DE"];
      var date = new Date();
      var counts = dimensions.map(dim => [date, dim, getValue(dim)[0].aggregations[0].value]);
      return counts;
    }
  ```

Comment: Thankyou! This works perfectly. I had to change one thing based on the array output from the API. Instead to getting dimensions I changed it to aggregations and it works perfectly. Thanks for your speedy answer.

Comment: I changed - var counts = dimensions.map(dim => [date, dim, getValue(dim)[0].dimensions[0].value]); TO this - var counts = dimensions.map(dim => [date, dim, getValue(dim)[0].aggregations[0].value]);

Comment: @racker Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I updated my answer.